# The angular documentation says that restrict applies to attributes (A) and elements (E). The source code says (AC) - why?

Tags: angularjs

The angular [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile) says that restrict applies to attributes (A) and elements (E).

> `restrict`
>
> String of subset of EACM which restricts the directive to a specific
>   directive declaration style. If omitted, the **defaults (elements and
>   attributes)** are used.
>
> **E - Element name (default)**: `<my-directive></my-directive>`
>
> **A - Attribute (default):** `<div my-directive="exp"></div>`
>
> C - Class: `<div> class="my-directive: exp;"></div>`
>
> M - Comment: `<!-- directive: my-directive exp -->`

The source [code](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/directive/directives.js#L9) says (AC) - why the discrepancy, or am I misreading the code?

```
function ngDirective(directive) {
  if (isFunction(directive)) {
    directive = {
      link: directive
    };
  }
  directive.restrict = directive.restrict || 'AC'; // HERE
  return valueFn(directive);
}
```

Comment: Just means that by default directives are restricted to either an **A**ttribute, or a **C**lass

Comment: If you register _your own_ directive then the documentation snippet you posted applies. The corresponding line can be found in [`compile.js`](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/compile.js#L777) under the `registerDirective` function.

Comment: Oh that's angular's internal directive-making function, then?  Make that an answer and I'll upvote/accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Directives that *you create yourself* will be restricted to being used as elements or attributes by default.

The [`registerDirective`](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/compile.js#L777) function in `compile.js` contains the code relevant to the documentation snippet that you've posted (i.e. custom directives default `restrict` to elements and attributes).

And as @Jhecht mentioned, it's the built-in directives (i.e. `ng-repeat`, `ng-style`, etc.) that are restricted to attributes and comments by default.